# recover deleted xbox360 profile from Flash Drive?

Tags: usb-flash-drive, xbox360

I have a 8GB Usb flash drive and I configured it from xbox 360 for 1 GB. SO that I can use Pen Drive in both PC and 360. Accidentally I deleted all files from pen drive now My profile is also deleted how do I restore deleted files ? I'm on windows 7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I was able to recover my profile. Here is what I did.
I used Handy Recovery software and recovered a folder named xbox360. So I put the folder back to usb flash drive and voilla I got my profile back as it is.